# How to create a table with user input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, user-input

I'm a newbie in development, so any help is welcome :)

**Here's my Problem:**

I'm using next.js - this might be important, because f.ex. document.createElement seem only work with useEffect.

I created a text area, where users add words separated with a comma (f.ex. "Nike, Adidas, New Balance"). I want to rewrite the existing code below, so that:

- table is only visible/appears, when a user adds something in the inputbox
- each word from the inputbox (f.ex. Nike, Adidas) creates a new row in the table (in table head "Brand").

By now, I was trying to use the .split and .forEach method to create a new Element(table). But I just can't make it work - maybe it's just not the right solution. Any help is welcome!

```js
function Analyzer() {
  
  const [brand, setBrand] = React.useState('');
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setBrand(event.target.value.split(','))};
  
  return(            
    <div>
      <textarea type="text" 
              placeholder="Example:
              Nike, Adidas, New Balance ..." 
              onChange={handleChange}></textarea>

      <table className={styles.table}>
         <thead>
             <tr>
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>Brand</th>
                <th>Also known as</th>
                <th>Avg. price</th>
             </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                 <td>1</td>
                 <td>{brand}</td>
                 <td></td>
                 <td><input type= "number"></input>%</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>

     </div>);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following. What I did was extract the `Table` component out and put any conditions for its rendering within it. You can even create a separate file for this component and pass any relevant props to it.

Secondly, I am putting the list of brands into state as `brands` within the `handleChange` function. This state variable is then iterated over using `.map` to render each row in the table.

```
function Analyzer() {
  const [brands, setBrands] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    const { value } = target;
    setBrands(value.split(','));
  };

  const Table = () => {
    if (!brands || brands.length === 0) return null;

    return (
      <table className={styles.table}>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Also known as</th>
            <th>Avg. price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {brands.map((brand) => (
             <tr>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>{brand}</td>
               <td></td>
               <td><input type= "number"></input>%</td>
             </tr>
           )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  };

  return(            
    <div>
      <input 
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Example: Nike, Adidas, New Balance ..."
        type="text"
        value={brands}
      />
      <Table />
   </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and the explanation! I think I understand your idea. I will check it and give an update, if everything worked out!

Comment: I modified a bit the code, the validation `!brands || brands === ''` will never work because your `brands` default value is an array. Anyway, your map function will return nothing if the array is empty, so no need to have validation there (table will be rendered with 0 data row). if you need the validation, better to check if its an empty array.

Comment: I checked the code and the table works perfectly (only added the optional index-parameter in .map). Thank you guys! There is only a small issue: I can see the table head even if there's no input. Is it possible to make it invisible at the beginning? Tried to move brands.map to the top, but then the head is shown multiple times.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I had the condition at the beginning of the table component. I've edited it back (though differently) to check whether there are items in the array. I did this because we don't want to render the table at all if there is no input.

Comment: Great. Everything works now. I saved it as a component in a separate file - thanks for the tip!